# Selecting a specific Android AVD Dreamweaver CS 5.5

Tags: android, dreamweaver

The recent upgrade to Dreamweaver CS5.5 finally installs the Android SDK correctly, but when using the Build & Emulate feature it only launches the 4.0.3 AVD.

How do you tell it to launch one of the other AVD's such as 2.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick answer > Android 4.0.3 is the default emulation platform , you can change to other platforms through the Manage AVDs dialog. **Detailed steps below**

Go to Site > Mobile Applications > Application Settings
In the resulting Native Application Settings Dialog, provide the Author Name and Under the Select Target OS Version Click on Manage AVDs …

You will see Android SDK Manager’s Tools tab on the top of your screen, Click on Tools >  Manage AVDs..

The resulting dialog lists the existing AVDs

Click on New ..

Provide the Name for the New AVD and select the preferred Target platform from the Target dropdown.You can leave the rest of the options to default.

Close the dialog and return to the Native Application Settings dialog.

From the dropdown for the Target OS for Android , you can see the New AVD listed, Select It and Save.

You can now Build and emulate on the New Platform!!!

..Harish